# Adding css files in head resulting in error DOMPDF

Tags: php, html, opencart, dompdf

Iam using open cart.
I have a  information page which has a form. form method is post.In my controller i initialise my data arrays with post variables. than in my tpl file i have another form in which i show the output which user filled (Designed styled well ). working Fine.
Now when ever a form is filled i convert it into PDF using DOMPDF i write it on my server and below this code i use opencart mail lib. to send attached file to user i want.. working great

**If i include all my css files in head section of TPL where i show output it gives me error**

```
    Fatal error: Call to a member function prepend_child() on a non-object in /home/ifixandm/public_html/finalUpGrade/system/library/dompdf/include/frame_tree.cls.php on line 218
```

But if i remove css files it sends email with attached pdf but style is not applied (like bootstrap coloumns etc)

**I have noticed that only bootstrap.css file which is included in head is causing me problem.**

Answer (score 0):

dompdf prior to v0.6.1 had trouble with global :before/:after styling. This particular issue has been [addressed in v0.6.1](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/758). However, that does not mean that you'll get the desired layout in your final document. Quite a bit of work is left to be done before dompdf can [fully support Bootstrap](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/631).

Comment: Does it support tables for example if i create a table and create a tr with two td so that i can show two columns in front of each other will it work bec bootstrap isnt working

Comment: Dompdf does support tables, though there are some limitations. The biggest issue is that a table cell can not exceed the height of a single page. If you have a specific layout question you might start a new question with details on the layout you want to see plus what you have tried.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add css files in your controller like:

```
if(file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . '/stylesheet/example.css')) {
    $this->document->addStyle(DIR_TEMPLATE . '/stylesheet/example.css');
}
```

but with change the path :)

Comment: I have realised that only the bootstrap file is causing me problems i have used col-md-6 in my form for output just those are missing if i dont include bootstrap in head of tpl it fine just in single column but i need two columns.. Including bootstrap in controller doesnt make scense to me